Disabling one of the displays from the system service C#
I am trying to disable EDP conected display from C# System Service:
    public class EDPController
    {
        [Flags]
        private enum SdcFlags : uint
        {
            Zero = 0,
            Apply = 0x00000080,
            UseSuppliedDisplayConfig = 0x00000020,
            PathPersistIfRequired = 0x00001000,
            AllowChanges = 0x00000400,
            SaveToDatabase = 0x00000200,
        }

        private enum QueryDisplayFlags : uint
        {
            AllPaths = 0x00000001
        }

        private enum DisplayConfigVideoOutputTechnology : uint
        {
            Hdmi = 5,
            DisplayportExternal = 6,
            EmbeddedDisplayport = 11, // eDP identifier
            Internal = 10,
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct DisplayConfigPathInfo
        {
            public DisplayConfigPathSourceInfo sourceInfo;
            public DisplayConfigPathTargetInfo targetInfo;
            public uint flags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct DisplayConfigPathSourceInfo
        {
            public uint adapterIdLowPart;
            public uint adapterIdHighPart;
            public uint id;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;
            public uint statusFlags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct DisplayConfigPathTargetInfo
        {
            public uint adapterIdLowPart;
            public uint adapterIdHighPart;
            public uint id;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;
            public DisplayConfigVideoOutputTechnology outputTechnology;
            public uint rotation;
            public uint scaling;
            public uint refreshRateNumerator;
            public uint refreshRateDenominator;
            public uint scanLineOrdering;
            public bool targetAvailable;
            public uint statusFlags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct DisplayConfigModeInfo
        {
            public uint infoType;
            public uint id;
            public uint adapterIdLowPart;
            public uint adapterIdHighPart;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(
            QueryDisplayFlags flags,
            out uint numPathArrayElements,
            out uint numModeInfoArrayElements);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(
            QueryDisplayFlags flags,
            ref uint numPathArrayElements,
            [Out] DisplayConfigPathInfo[] pathArray,
            ref uint numModeInfoArrayElements,
            [Out] DisplayConfigModeInfo[] modeInfoArray,
            IntPtr currentTopologyId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetDisplayConfig(
            uint numPathArrayElements,
            [In] DisplayConfigPathInfo[] pathArray,
            uint numModeInfoArrayElements,
            [In] DisplayConfigModeInfo[] modeInfoArray,
            SdcFlags flags);

        private const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0;

        public void DisableEDP()
        {
            ModifyEDPState(false);
        }

        public void EnableEDP()
        {
            ModifyEDPState(true);
        }

        private void ModifyEDPState(bool enable)
        {
            uint pathCount, modeCount;

            // Get buffer sizes for display paths and modes
            int result = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QueryDisplayFlags.AllPaths, out pathCount, out modeCount);
            if (result != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
                throw new Exception("Failed to get display configuration buffer sizes.");

            var paths = new DisplayConfigPathInfo[pathCount];
            var modes = new DisplayConfigModeInfo[modeCount];

            // Query the current display configuration
            result = QueryDisplayConfig(QueryDisplayFlags.AllPaths, ref pathCount, paths, ref modeCount, modes, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (result != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
                throw new Exception("Failed to query display configuration.");

            // Modify the path to enable/disable the eDP display
            for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
            {
                if (paths[i].targetInfo.outputTechnology == DisplayConfigVideoOutputTechnology.EmbeddedDisplayport
                    || paths[i].targetInfo.outputTechnology == DisplayConfigVideoOutputTechnology.Internal)
                {
                    if (enable)
                    {
                        paths[i].flags &= ~(uint)0x2; // Clear the "disabled" flag
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        paths[i].flags |= 0x2; // Set the "disabled" flag
                    }
                }
            }

            // Apply the updated display configuration
            result = SetDisplayConfig(pathCount, paths, modeCount, modes, SdcFlags.Apply | SdcFlags.UseSuppliedDisplayConfig);
            if (result != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
                throw new Exception($"Failed to {(enable ? "enable" : "disable")} eDP monitor.");
        }
    }

10 and 5 are displays found in paths so I only focus on them and tried to disable both. But in real app I will disable the default EDp-connected display.
Unfortunately, the only effect I have is a short blink but not disabling. Is there any  way to disable the monitor from System Service (Ie no access to UI)?
Addtional explanation for close vote users:
I am trying to disable a monitor so that it stops displaying anything and enable it again to resume display.
During testing, I have two monitors:

Internal Display (likely eDP, identified with 5).
HDMI Display (identified with 10).

I want to disable the Internal Display (or both displays in some tests). However, when I attempt to disable them, the screens only blink briefly, and the displays remain active. What could be causing this, and how can I fix it to properly disable the monitor(s)?

Closing vote users - what is not clear. I want do disable the monitor (ie not display anything) or enable it - ie to display. What is not clear here? During testing I have two monitors and they are identified as Intenal (5 probably EDp) and Hdmi (10). In the test I try to disable Internal.  I tried to disable both but it does not work either. They just blink for a short time
